# In Solidity, what's the difference between funtion type and funtion?

Tags: solidity

In Solidity, what's the difference between funtion type and funtion?
And what can they be used for and how respectively?
Thanks!

Comment: They are fundamentally different things. A function is a sequence of instructions that executes an action, and a function type is a type that holds a reference to a function.

Answer (score 1):

Function types can be internal,external, public or private functions where a function is just a normal function that can be classified as one of these types.

1. **Public functions** can be called from anywhere.
2. **Private functions** can only be called from inside the contract.
3. **Internal functions** can be called inside the current contract but includes inherited functions and libraries.
4. **External functions** can be called inside or outside the contract.

Comment: "function is just a normal function" - that's a circular definition! The blame on this can be ascribed mostly to the question itself, though, I would still refrain from stating this "recursive definition" to begin with (and I would more generally refrain from answering that ill-phrased question altogether).

Comment: I assume as a programmer, they understand what we mean if we speak about a "normal function". But to clear things up, what I mean by a normal function is: a block of organized, reusable code that is used to perform a single, related action.

Comment: A programmer wouldn't ask "what's the difference between funtion type and funtion". The most accurate equivalence of *function type* which I can think of is *function prototype* or *function signature*, meaning it argument types and return-value type. This is also backed by the fact that if you want to pass a function pointer to another function, then you need to specify all of that, as well as the function access-level (e.g., `internal view`, etc). In that sense, your answer is flawed because it assumes that only public/private/external/internal matter.